# I have much more than three elements in every class, but I get this error: "class cannot be less than k=3 in scikit-learn"

Tags: runtime-error, svm, scikit-learn, cross-validation

This is my target (y):

```
target = [7,1,2,2,3,5,4,
      1,3,1,4,4,6,6,
      7,5,7,8,8,8,5,
      3,3,6,2,7,7,1,
      10,3,7,10,4,10,
      2,2,2,7]
```

I do not know why while I'm executing:

```
...
# Split the data set in two equal parts
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Set the parameters by cross-validation
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]

scores = ['precision', 'recall']

for score in scores:
    print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
    print()

    clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1), tuned_parameters)#scoring non esiste
    # I get an error in the line below
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train, cv=5)
...
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\SVMpredictCROSSeGRID.py", line 232, in <module>
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, cv=5)  #The minimum number of labels for any class cannot be less than k=3.
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 354, in fit
return self._fit(X, y)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 372, in _fit
cv = check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1148, in check_cv
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, cv, indices=is_sparse)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 358, in __init__
" be less than k=%d." % (min_labels, k))
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too few. The minimum number of labels for any class cannot be less than k=3.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The algorithm requires that there be at least 3 instances for a label in your training set. Although your `target` array contains at least 3 instances of each label, but when you split the data between training and testing, not all the training labels have 3 instances.

You either need to merge some class labels or increase your training samples to solve the problem.

Comment: You could also pass a "cv" parameter, for example "KFold". Which version do you have btw, I think the input validation for StratifiedKFold (the default cv) got less strict in newer version of sklearn. Be careful in interpreting the results, though. They are probably not that meaningful.

Comment: @AndreasMueller, Haven't tried input validation in case of  StratifiedKFold. I will definitely check. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't split the test and training set with each class populated enough in each fold, then try updating the Scikit library.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

You'll get the same message as a warning, so you can run the code.